# SQL Server 2008 and 2012 side by side

Tags: sql-server-2012

After installing SQL Server 2012 Express with SP1, I'm unable to install SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Express. I've followed all the advice here for rerunning the install and checking the "feature" box for this component. However, it seems that 2012 won't install it's newest version of the Management Studio because I still have the 2008 version. Apparently, this is a shared component.

My question: should I uninstall the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio and then go through the install process again to get the 2012 version? Is there a problem with using the 2008 version of Management Studio with the 2012 engine? Are there some benefits for the newest version? I really hate risking some other problems by doing uninstalls if it's really not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: I've got 2008 and 2012 management studio running side by side on this machine. I don't recall doing anything special when installing 2012. (Edit: Developer edition though so maybe Express is different)

Comment: What does "seems that it won't install" mean? Can you share the actual error message you get? They should install side by side without problem, but do you have a specific reason you need to keep the old 2008 version around? [Have you downloaded the quasi-standalone installer for SSMS Express (SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579)?

Comment: According to other suggestions posted here, I ran SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe (which includes sp1)  to get up to the point of checking which features to add.  It seems there should be a checkbox for the Management Studio - there is none.  There was no explicit error.  I'm assuming it didn't offer this feature as the 2008 counterpart is still on my machine.  My main question is whether or not the 2012 version provides different features or if I could run into problems using the 2008 mgt studio with the 2012 DB engine?  Or vice versa. I've found no separate download for just the studio. Thanks.

Comment: I finally uninstalled all of 2008 and 2012 and then reinstalled 2012 and restored data from backups.  The 2012 management studio appeared as expected and all seems to be working OK - except for all the time I blew fooling around with this.